# Python socket timeout only when called from a RenciSSH.Net session

Tags: c#, sockets, python-3.x, ssh.net

I have a python 3.4 script that makes a socket connection to a remote host, sends data, and gets a 'OK' message back from the remote host.
It runs fine if executed directly from the terminal on my Ubuntu server 14.04. Here's the relavant section of the python script:

```
try:
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.settimeout(15)
    sock.connect(("10.191.0.2", 6874))
    dataSend = "<request>" + command + "</request>"
    sock.send(dataSend.encode('utf_8'))
    dataRecv = sock.recv(512).decode('utf_8')
    if dataRecv and "'OK'" in dataRecv:
        return "OK"
    else:
        return "Error."
except socket.timeout as err1:
    return "Error:" + str(err1)
except socket.error as err2:
    return "Error:" + str(err2)
finally:
    sock.close()
```

However, if I run this via a Renci SSH.Net session initiated from a third host, I get a timeout on socket.connect().
Here's the C#/Renci code (I'm using SSH.Net version 2106.0.0)

```
using (var sshClient = new SshClient(host, user, keyfile))
{
    sshClient.Connect();
    SshCommand cmd = null;
    try
    {
        sshClient.ConnectionInfo.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOut);
        cmd = sshClient.RunCommand(command);
    }
    catch (SshOperationTimeoutException timeoutex)
    {
        Trace.TraceError(string.Format("SshOperationTimeoutException executing command \"{0}\" on {1}: {2}", command, sshClient.ConnectionInfo.Host, timeoutex.ToString()));
    }
    catch (SshException ex)
    {
        Trace.TraceError(string.Format("SshException executing command \"{0}\" on {1}: {2} ", command, sshClient.ConnectionInfo.Host, ex.ToString()));
    }
}
```

I'm stumped as to why this runs fine locally but not over the SSH.Net session. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: Have you tried with just a normal SSH connection and executing the exact same command?

Comment: Yes, it works fine over a normal ssh session as well. It just fails over the SSH.Net session.

Answer (score 0):

OK - I found the problem. My Python method was marked with @staticmethod. After removing this attribute, the code runs fine over the SSH.Net session.

If anyone cares to comment on why this is the case, I'm all ears.